# SSIS Format Date YYYYMMDD with day offset of X days?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, ssis, datetimeoffset

This below evaluation will give me a date set to the format yyyymmdd as an int.

What I need to do it have the ability in SSIS to offset the day by X days and keep the month and year offset accordingly.

I cant seem to find the answer.  Everyone has an example on how to format it liek below, but what if you need to format it with an offset in days, months or years and at the same time keep all parts accurate.

```
RIGHT((DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR(DATEADD("dd",0,getdate())),4) +""+
RIGHT("0"  +(DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH(DATEADD("dd",-1,getdate())),2)+""+
RIGHT("0" +(DT_STR,4,1252)DAY(DATEADD("dd",0,getdate())) ,2)
```

Anyone?

In C# or TSQL this is easy, but this SSIS is growing my patience thin.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you execute a stored procedure and load the results into a variable, or use a script task and set the variable there?  That seems like a better solution as the expressions are not designed to handle much complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that will allow you to achieve this.

In the SSIS package, declare four package scope variables.

1. **TodaysDate** - Variable of type `DateTime`. When you set to DateTime, the variable will be assigned with current date and time. You can also change this and set it to the date of your choice.
2. **OffsetValue** - Variable of type `Int32`. This will hold the offset value. For this example, I am choosing the offset value to be in terms of days. So, I have set it to a value of 7.
3. **OffsetDate** - Variable of type `DateTime`. Select this variable and press F4 to view the properties. Change the property **EvaluateAsExpression** to `True`. Set the **Expresstion** to the value `DATEADD( "dd", @[User::OffsetValue] , @[User::TodaysDate]  )`. This expressions adds the offset value to the variable TodaysDate so you get the new OffsetDate.
4. **FormattedDate** - Variable of type `String`. Select this variable and press F4 to view the properties. Change the property **EvaluateAsExpression** to `True`. Set the **Expresstion** to the following value

`RIGHT((DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR(DATEADD("dd",0, @[User::OffsetDate] )),4) +""+
RIGHT("0"  +(DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH(DATEADD("dd",-1,@[User::OffsetDate])),2)+""+
RIGHT("0" +(DT_STR,4,1252)DAY(DATEADD("dd",0,@[User::OffsetDate])) ,2)`

The only difference is you are formatting the date of your choice, here in this case the value in variable `OffsetDate`. This variable will hold the date that has already been offset.

The below screenshot shows a sample. The variable TodaysDate is set to `11/28/2011`. Adding 7 days to the variable sets the field OffsetDate to `12/05/2011`. As you can see, the variable FormattedDate formats the newly offset date to `20111205`.

This example can also be done with **one** less variable by eliminating the variable **TodaysDate**. You can also have one offset variable for each type like days, months and years. It all comes down to ones' preference.

[image: Example]

I hope this is what you were looking for and probably gives you an idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: Also just be aware that anything that is going to use the date variables you will probably want to set delayvalidation on, so as to ensure that SSIS computes the correct value at runtime.

Comment: Shiva, thank you very much, it gives me a step forward for sure!!!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to do the date manipulation and formatting in a Script Task. (Assuming you're using SSIS 2008, Script Tasks can be written in C#.)

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC2\\u_ex" + 
    RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yy" , DATEADD( "dd" , -1, getdate() ) ), 2) +
    RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , DATEADD( "dd" , -1, getdate() ) ), 2) +
    RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , DATEADD( "dd" , -1, getdate() ) ), 2) + ".log"
```